# How to pass the output of SELECT to a function expecting a table?

Tags: t-sql

I have a function that knows to split strings by comma:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings('15,29')
```

Returns

```
Item
15
29
```

I also have a function that knows to join strings by comma:

```
DECLARE @table AS SmallStrings
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')
SELECT dbo.JoinStrings(@table) Joined
```

Returns

```
Joined
a,b,c
```

Now I want to split a string, modify each item and join them back. I can do that too:

```
DECLARE @tmp SmallStrings
INSERT INTO @tmp SELECT dbo.DayOfMonthExprToCron2(Item) Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings('15,29')
SELECT dbo.JoinStrings(@tmp) Result
```

Returns

```
Result
15,L
```

Now I wonder if I can pass the result of `SELECT dbo.DayOfMonthExprToCron2(Item) Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings('15,29')` directly into `dbo.JoinStrings`

I tried and failed - my humble attempts do not even compile.

The naive one:

```
SELECT dbo.JoinStrings(SELECT dbo.DayOfMonthExprToCron2(Item) Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings('15,29')) Result
```

Results in

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

### Edit

Another attempt (using double parentheses):

```
SELECT dbo.JoinStrings((SELECT dbo.DayOfMonthExprToCron2(Item) Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings('15,29'))) Result
```

Results in

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with SmallStrings
```

I realize that the code is needed, so here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings](@List NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a 
      CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JoinStrings](@strings SmallStrings READONLY)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res NVARCHAR(32) 
    SELECT @res = COALESCE(@res + ',', '') + Item 
    FROM @strings
    WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
    RETURN @res
END

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SmallStrings] AS TABLE([Item] [nvarchar](5) NULL)

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DayOfMonthExprToCron2](@dayOfMonthExpr NVARCHAR(32))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dayOfMonth INT = CAST(@dayOfMonthExpr AS INT)

    RETURN CASE WHEN @dayOfMonth < 29 THEN @dayOfMonthExpr ELSE 'L' END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible.

I poked around the documentation of table value parameters ([TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)) and around the web for any hint.

I also tried using a very simplified set set of functions and couldn't make it work.